# Как вычислить прогноз по выходным коэффициентам Support Vector Machine?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Если представить, что обученная машина опорных векторов с RBF ядром больше не будет корректироваться и повторно обучаться, то как составить формулу предсказания имея коэффициенты (support_vectors_, dual_coef_, intercept_)? Я не математик, сложных формул к сожалению не понимаю. В Python нагляднее будет представить, типа для линейной версии:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons

x, y = make_moons(100, shuffle=True, random_state=11)

x_train, x_test = x[:75], x[75:]
y_train, y_test = y[:75], y[75:]

clf = SVC(kernel='linear')
estimator = clf.fit(x, y)

similar_prediction = (np.dot(x_test, estimator.coef_.T.ravel()) + estimator.intercept_) > 0
any(~(estimator.predict(x_test) == similar_prediction))
```